# routing issue rails 3.1 thums_up and forem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I am trying to integrate forem with thumbs_up. I have inherited the forem Post model and controller.

Here is my controller :-

```
  class PostsController < Forem::PostsController
    def vote_up
    begin
      current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))
      render :nothing => true, :status => 200
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      render :nothing => true, :status => 404
    end
  end
end
```

Here is how the Post Controller of Forem looks like :-

```
module Forem
  class PostsController < Forem::ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_forem_user
    before_filter :find_topic
    .
    .
    .
    .
private

    def find_topic
      @topic = Forem::Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my routes:-

```
 mount Forem::Engine, :at => "/forums"

resources :posts do
  member do
    post :vote_up
  end
end
```

Here is my view :-

```
<%= link_to t('vote for this post!', :scope =>"forem.post"), main_app.vote_up_post_path(@post), :method => :post %>
```

This is the error which I am getting :-

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#vote_up
>
> Couldn't find Forem::Topic without an ID

What could be the issue?

Comment: What does `current_user.vote_for` look like?

Comment: @muistooshort what do you mean by how does current_user.vote_for look like? vote_for is provided by the thumbs_up gem

Comment: Looks like `current_user.vote_for` is doing calling `Forem::Topic.find` without give it an ID, that's what the error message seems to be telling you and I don't see anything else that could be causing it so I'm wondering why `vote_for` is doing something that it shouldn't be doing.

Comment: @muistooshort here is the link https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up/blob/master/lib/acts_as_voteable.rb of thumbs_up gem which I think has vote_for action defined. If you have some time then please look into it

Comment: also I am inheriting my postscontroller from forem::postscontroller could that be a problem? In the sense that postscontroller is calling Forem:Topic.find? It actually does a before_filter find_topic

Comment: I'll bet you a fresh baked pie that the `before_filter :find_topic` is the root of the problem. If I'm wrong you'll have to come to Whister to collect though :) You might want to add those details to your question.

Comment: @muistooshort:) sure doing it right away

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6578/discussion-between-dev-r-and-mu-is-too-short)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the before filter:

```
module Forem
  class PostsController < Forem::ApplicationController
    #...
    before_filter :find_topic
    #...
    def find_topic
      @topic = Forem::Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    end
```

and then:

```
class PostsController < Forem::PostsController
  def vote_up
    #...
```

So `find_topic` will be called before `vote_up` but the route for `vote_up` won't have a `:topic_id`; no `:topic_id` means that `find_topic` will be doing this:

```
@topic = Forem::Topic.find(nil)
```

and that's where your error comes from.

Three options come to mind:

1. Move `vote_up` to a separate controller class that doesn't inherit from `Forem::ApplicationController`.
2. Add a [`skip_filter :find_topic, :only => :vote_up`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_filter) to PostsController.
3. Adjust the route and link to get a `:topic_id` in the route.

If upvoting doesn't need the `@topic` then (1) or (2) would work, otherwise you'll have to go with (3).

Comment: I dont know how to go ahead with option 3, have tried option 1 and 2 but that does not seem to work. I guess @topic will be required because I think the architecture of forem is forum --> topic --> post any ideas?

Comment: @Dev: Is there any association between topics and posts? If there is then you can get your `@topic` from your `@post` instead of from `params`.

Comment: this is the association has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy, :order => "created_at ASC"

Answer (score 0):

check `rake routes`in command prompt,
 and check id should be post :vote_up OR get:vote_up – ror_master

and use `debugger` in controller!
and write `params` there perhaps you will get solution.

Comment: I think you should have use
`get:vote_up`
in routes. Please check and verify.